# Что такое $this?

Tags: php, ооп, this

Никак не могу понять что собой представляет $this в PHP ООП. Вроде бы и ясно, а вроде бы и нет, объясните кто может, зарание спасибо на ответ!

Comment: http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2):

Это специальная переменная содержащая ссылку на текущий объект.
Через неё можно обращаться к свойствам и методам объекта.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` - это обращение к переменной или методу в контексте класса.

Самый простой пример:

```
<?php

class Product {
    private title;

    public function __construct($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getProductTitle() { 
        return $this->title;
    }
}

$product = Product('Potato');
echo $product->getProductTitle()
```

При попытке в `getProductTitle()` выполнить `return $title` будет ошибка, поскольку `$title` нету в контексте метода `getProductTitle()`.

Answer (score 2):

Это ссылка на самого себя внутри класса. Проще даже привести пример на `С++`, т.к. там есть прямая работа в памятью.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:

    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "address of this: " << this << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;

    std::cout << "address of t: " << &t << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Компилируя `clang++ test.cpp` и запуская `./a.out` получим результат:

```
address of this: 0x7ffd8f854b07
address of t: 0x7ffd8f854b07
```

Отсюда видно, что `this` буквально указывает на тот-же объект в памяти, что и переменная `t`, только, по сути, позволяет этой переменной `t` как-бы обратиться к самой-себе из своих собственных методов (функций).

Эта же концепция использутся и в `PHP`.